# Convergence of the series $\sum n!/(n^2+3)$

Tags: sequences-and-series, divergent-series

How can we test if this series diverges/converges?

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty\frac{n!}{n^2+3}$$

I tried D'Alembert's principle and tried to do $\frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}$ but I'm stuck. Any help?

Comment: Do the terms of the series approach $0$?

Comment: My notes don't say anything else. Just find the convergence/divergence of the series. But the terms approach $+\infty$, no?

Comment: I agree, the terms $\rightarrow\infty$.  In a convergent series, what must the terms approach?

Comment: They must approach $0$.

Comment: Is it correct if I did the root theorem and then found that the limit of the n-root is $+\infty$ and thus the series diverges?

Comment: That would work too.  But it is more than you need.  That the terms don't approach $0$ is enough to conclude divergence.  (This result is sometimes called the $n$th term test for divergence.)

Answer (score 2):

**BIG HINT:**

$$\lim\limits_{n\to\infty}\frac{n!}{n^2+3}=\infty$$

Answer (score 0):

get the lower bound on the summand and show it doesn't tend to $0$, like
$a_n >(n-3)! \to \infty$.

Answer (score 0):

For $n\geqslant 2$, $n!\geqslant n(n-1)(n-2)\geqslant (n-2)^3$, hence for $n\geqslant 4$, using the inequalities $n-2\geqslant n/2$ and $n^2\geqslant 1$,
$$\frac{n!}{n^2+3}\geqslant\frac{(n-2)^3}{n^2+1}\geqslant \frac{n^3}{2(n^2+1)}\geqslant \frac{n^3}{2\cdot 2n^2}.$$